# Query Analysis Services Tabular Model Relationships

Tags: visual-studio, ssas

Is there a way to use DAX or MDX to query the Analysis Services Tabular Model Relationships?

I would like it to return the same tables that I get in Visual Studio when I do Manage Relationships...
     Active
     Table 1
     Cardinality
     Filter Direction
     Table 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no DAX function where you can get the relationships, but there are DMVs for things like that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions